# What's the best way to unit test a method with a parameter that's immutable and does not have an initializer?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing

**Question**

I'm trying to unit test my implementation of a protocol's method that takes an immutable object that's not in my project as a parameter. This object doesn't have any initializers exposed that set its properties. What's the best way to unit test in this scenario?

**What I tried**

I tried subclassing and casting the properties to readwrite, but you only have access to a super-class' ivars if they're explicitly marked as @protected. Since the class isn't within my project, I can't re-assign a new scope to the ivar.

I also can't mock a setter that doesn't exist, and ivars are not directly writable through mock objects.

Eventually, I decided to add an additional method that the method in question would call, passing only objects whose properties I can set, and I covered that additional method in unit tests.

Is there a better way to unit test in this scenario?

**Specifics of my scenario**

I'm trying to unit test my implementation of [userContentController:didReceiveScriptMessage:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkscriptmessagehandler/1396222-usercontentcontroller?language=objc) from WebKit's WKScriptMessageHandler protocol and can't find a way to pass an instance of WKScriptMessage or of WKUserContentController with any properties set.

To unit test this, I created a new method that takes a parameter of type 'id' and called it from userContentController:didReceiveScriptMessage:, passing WKScriptMessage's [body](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkscriptmessage/1417901-body?language=objc) property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help you?

TestMessage.h

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface TestMessage : WKScriptMessage

- (id) initWithBody:(id)body
          frameInfo:(WKFrameInfo*)frameInfo
               name:(NSString*)name
            webView:(WKWebView*)webView;

@end
```

TestMessage.m

```
#import "TestMessage.h"

@interface TestMessage()

@property (nonatomic, strong) id messageBody;
@property (nonatomic, strong) WKFrameInfo* messageFrameInfo;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* messageName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) WKWebView* messageWebView;

@end

@implementation TestMessage

- (id) initWithBody:(id)body
          frameInfo:(WKFrameInfo*)frameInfo
               name:(NSString*)name
            webView:(WKWebView*)webView
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        _messageBody = body;
        _messageFrameInfo = frameInfo;
        _messageName = name;
        _messageWebView = webView;
    }

    return self;
}

- (id) body
{
    return self.messageBody;
}

- (WKFrameInfo *)frameInfo
{
    return self.frameInfo;
}

- (NSString *)name
{
    return self.messageName;
}

- (WKWebView *)webView
{
    return self.messageWebView;
}

@end
```

So you're basically creating a subclass with matching properties and then overriding the getters for the superclass properties to return values for the ones you have full access to.

This worked for me with the simple test (I'm sure your scenario is more involved):

```
- (void) testMessageHandler
{
    WKWebView* webView = [[WKWebView alloc] init];
    WKUserContentController* controller = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
    WKFrameInfo* info = [[WKFrameInfo alloc] init];
    NSDictionary* testBody = @{@"testKey" : @"testVal" };

    TestMessage* testMessage = [[TestMessage alloc] initWithBody:testBody
                                                       frameInfo:info
                                                            name:@"Message Name"
                                                         webView:webView];

    // some object conforming to the WKScriptMessageHandler protocol
    [self userContentController:controller
        didReceiveScriptMessage:testMessage];
}


- (void)userContentController:(nonnull WKUserContentController *)userContentController
      didReceiveScriptMessage:(nonnull WKScriptMessage *)message
{
    NSLog(@"Received Script Message... (%@)", message.body);
}
```

Comment: It does! That's exactly what I needed. Thanks for sharing